# Can I put something into a react component and get it back in useEffect?

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, classname

I would like to pass a variable into a function that is in the className property (not anywhere else)

This function runs as soon as that specific jsx part is read (after the component function, before mount).

As a side effect this function returns a string for the className.

Then I want the same function to run after all the components are mounted =  `useEffect(() => { //here },[]`  with the same variable

```
const run = (val: any) => val 

useEffect(() => {
  const val = run() 
  console.log(val); // return 'go'
}, [])

return (
 <>
  <button className={ run('go') }>
    run
  </button>
 </>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't understand what's className role and how to use it.
You don't pass a function to className, but a CSS class name, which will define the styling of the element.

If I understood correctly, you want `run()` function to run automatically every time the components renders, with a specific input which is `'go'`.

You can edit your useEffect hook like so:

```
const run = (val: any) => val 

useEffect(() => {
  const val = run('go') 
  console.log(val); // return 'go'
}, [])

return (
 <>
  <button>
    run
  </button>
 </>
)
```

Another option will be, for example, call a function through onClick event of the button, like this:

```
return (
 <>
  <button onClick={ run('go') }>
    run
  </button>
 </>
)
```

This way, the `run` function will be triggered every time the function rerenders.

You'll also have to remove the `useEffect` hook, as it will trigger the function on each rerender without any input, and it's not what you asked.

Comment: I would like to pass a variable to a jsx component since it is rendered before useEffect and then I want to run a function with that variable after the whole component is rendered. But the variable has to be passed into the jsx not the function before the jsx. Specifically, the className property.